# AS400 Online Server For Practicing

Tags: ibm-midrange

Please help me regarding a valid AS400 Online Server for Public which can be registered for money and for practice of RPGLE programming. I have tried for a www.texas400.com but this is not a valid server as it accepts card details but does not redirects to any thing.

AS400 people please help for the up and running public servers.

Thank You.

Comment: Off-topic due to asking to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ but I find [iDevCloud](http://iinthecloud.com/idev-cloud/) to be excellent.

Comment: Thank you for direction user5470962. Found iinwbsite costly and not cheaper than Adelgado solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to obtain a free account from http://pub1.de/
This free iSeries access is made available by http://www.rzkh.de/

Comment: They also have paid accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pay money. Just register an IBM Identity and you can configure your own IBM i. The IBM Power Development Cloud (PDP) is totally free.

http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/stg_com_sys_power-development-platform

Comment: I only see Linux LE on that page for "open source developers".  I was hoping for as/400 on Power PC hardware.

Comment: Try clicking on "PDP system details". There you see AIX, Linux and IBM i